# React Native Android Release APK

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run a release APK.

I download the bundle just fine, I create the signed APK via Android Studio, and I install it via `adb install`.

When I run the app, in log cat I see:

`Got JS Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const' Const declarations are not supported in strict mode`

and

`Got JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require`.

I thought RN was transpiled via babel. What gives?

Comment: If I replace all `const` declarations with `var` or `let`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Solved it by upgrading node to 4.2

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this now.

In 'use strict' mode you can specify const properties. There is no impact in the release APK build.